# Better alternative to large nested IF formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a list of food items, each associated with 3 numbers.  When I select that food item via dropdown menu *(on the left side of the screenshot, where I have selected "steak")*, I have it auto-populate the cells below it with those 3 associated numbers.  However, I currently do this via a **massive nested IF formula** *(as seen in screenshot)*.

I'm wondering what some more efficient ways to do it could be?
*Preferably a way that would allow me to add as many food items as possible.  Excel tells me the formula is too long, so I currently can't add anymore food items.*

[image: Screenshot of Excel worksheet - large nested IF formula]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Is using a VBA-function an option?

Comment: To be honest I didn't think someone could make it without using `VLOOKUP`. Now I know it's possible to use `IF` to substitute `VLOOKUP`. And yes, I know the formula limit. It's just cool to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `VLOOKUP`

Put these formulas below the red rows (which you used to input **Steak**)

```
=VLOOKUP(I4, $V$5:$Y$8, 2, FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(I4, $V$5:$Y$8, 3, FALSE)
=VLOOKUP(I4, $V$5:$Y$8, 4, FALSE)
```

Note: I'm assuming the steak row is row 4. I'm also assuming the Nutritional table ends at row 8. Adjust the $Y$8 part if your table has more.

Or `INDEX MATCH` variation

```
=INDEX($W$5:$W$8, MATCH(I4, $V$5:$V8, 0))
=INDEX($X$5:$X$8, MATCH(I4, $V$5:$V8, 0))
=INDEX($Y$5:$Y$8, MATCH(I4, $V$5:$V8, 0))
```

You can use `VLOOKUP` just fine, but `INDEX MATCH` is safer if you want to add column(s) in the nutritional table in the future.

**EDIT:**

If you got error because you have your food row is blank right now, wrap it up with `IFERROR` or `IF(ISBLANK)`

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP( ... ), 0)
=IF(ISBLANK(I4), 0, VLOOKUP( ... ))
```

Comment: You should add ", FALSE" after the look reference in your VLOOKUP's:
=VLOOKUP(I4, $V$5:$Y$8, 2, FALSE).
Some international users may also need to change the comma separator to a semi colon (;) =VLOOKUP(I4; $V$5:$Y$8; 2; FALSE) - not relevant for this user, but good info if someone else stumbles on it in a few months time.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.  I just came across the VLOOKUP and INDEX MATCH tactics before I posted this question last night.  Will definitely be trying this and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Oh my god.  Thank you so much haha.  I'm now using IF(ISBLANK(), 0, INDEX(...MATCH(...))) and it works SO WELL!  So much quicker and easier to edit than my massive IF function, and now I can have as many foods in there as I want!  Thanks a ton!